# How to correctly implement stfalcon's chatkit

Tags: java, android, layout, chatkit

I'm trying to implement a chat app using [stfalcon's ChatKit library](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit).  I've followed the docs in their repo, but there are things I'm not sure I'm getting right.

First, I created a new activity called `DialogsListActivity`, and copied [the xml](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_DIALOGS_LIST.MD#add-the-widget-into-your-xml-layout) in the activity's xml file. 
From [here](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_DIALOGS_LIST.MD) I first copied the xml part to the activity's xml file.

Next comes the [adapter setup](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_DIALOGS_LIST.MD#set-an-adapter). I copied the given code after the OnCreate method, including the last line (`dialogsListView.setAdapter(dialogsListAdapter);`) as the last line in OnCreate. The whole activity now looks like this:

```
    ListView dialogsListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialogs_list);
        dialogsListView.setAdapter(dialogsListAdapter);
    }

    DialogsListAdapter dialogsListAdapter = new DialogsListAdapter<>(dialogs, new ImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
            //If you using another library - write here your way to load image
            Picasso.with(DialogsListActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
        }
    });
}
```

Questions:

- is this the right place to put the adapter in?
- is it ok to put set the `dialogsListView` as an attribute and defining it inside OnCreate()?
- the `dialogs` from `new DialogsListAdapter` gets a `Cannot resolve symbol 'dialogs'` message.
- the `new ImageLoader()` from same place gets a `Class 'Anonymous class derived from ImageLoader' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'loadImage(ImageView, String, Object)' in 'ImageLoader'`

What am I missing there?

For the IDialog and IUser implementation I created the classes DefaultDialog and Author, and copied the given code. As I expected, the 'symbols' returned by the methods 'cannot be defined'. Where should they be defined and how?

Next in the tutorial is the [Data management section](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_DIALOGS_LIST.MD#data-management) which I think would *set* those values.

I already downloaded the sample project and tried to look inside, but I cannot find the `public class DefaultDialog` that `implements IDialog` or anything similar. Plus, I got pretty lost trying to understand the library from that sample project.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.